# how does GATE sentiment analysis work?

Tags: sentiment-analysis, gate

I successfully created a sentiment analysis pipeline as given in the exmaple: https://gate.ac.uk/sale/talks/gate-course-may10/track-3/module-11-ml-adv/module-11-sentiment.pdf
But now I want to work with a different corpus: it's german language; I have two files containing german phrases with positive or negative-feature. I wrote it into a .xml file like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<GateDocument>
<GateDocumentFeatures>
<Feature>
  <Name className="java.lang.String">gate.SourceURL</Name>
  <Value className="java.lang.String">file:/C:/Users/user/Documents/text</Value>
</Feature>
<Feature>
  <Name className="java.lang.String">MimeType</Name>
  <Value className="java.lang.String">text/plain</Value>
</Feature>
</GateDocumentFeatures>

<TextWithNodes>
<Node id="0" />10:41 Uhr &apos; Ist aber ein schwacher Trost. 
<Node id="47" />1969 das Problem der Entsorgung offiziell angesprochen. 
<Node id="103" />
...
</TextWithNodes>

<AnnotationSet Name="Key">
<Annotation Id="0" Type="comment" StartNode="0" EndNode="47">
<Feature>
  <Name className="java.lang.String">rating</Name>
  <Value className="java.lang.Double">2.0</Value>
</Feature>
</Annotation>
...
</AnnotationSet>
</GateDocument>
```

But I don't understand how to use the paum.xml:

1) In the example from the tutorial there was a String-rating-feature (e.g. "2_Star_Rating") instead of Double, but I have no idea how the paum.xml / pipeline processed this String-feature - and how can I tell my pipeline that I now have a Double value to work with?

2) When i run the batch learning PR in application mode: how does the text corpus have to loke like? Is plain text ok?

In a first trial I used the same paum.xml file from the tutorial and converted my rating from double (2.0) to Strings ("2_Star_Rating") - and no errors occurs on training and application mode - but when I looked at my text file (on which I ran my pipeline in app.mode), there have been no annotations set.

Comment: It would be ok if I work with String instead of double, just "convert" every double into "pos", "neg" or "neu". So question (2) is more important for me.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use a simplified XML like:

this is a comment1 text with opinion1

this is a comment2 text with opinion2

It can be a comment per-file or file with a lot of comments in one file.

Then you can use AnnotationSet Transfer PR and copy Annotations from "Original markups" to Default set after corpus population.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out what GATE is expecting:
The given document (which shall be analyzed) have to look like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<GateDocument>
<GateDocumentFeatures>
<Feature>
  <Name className="java.lang.String">gate.SourceURL</Name>
  <Value className="java.lang.String">file:/C:/Users/user/Documents/text</Value>
</Feature>
<Feature>
  <Name className="java.lang.String">MimeType</Name>
  <Value className="java.lang.String">text/html</Value>
</Feature>
</GateDocumentFeatures>
<TextWithNodes>
<Node id="0" />sentence1
<Node id="9" />
...
</TextWithNodes>

<AnnotationSet Name="Key">
<Annotation Id="1" Type="comment" StartNode="0" EndNode="9">
</Annotation>
...
</AnnotationSet>
</GateDocument>
```

Comment: OK, it's also possible (and easier) to use plain text and add a JAPE Transducer into the pipeline which adds an annotationSet to the text (in this case: name the annotations "comment" and set outputASname to "Key")